# apply a discount to product in Commerce

Tags: entities, commerce, rules

I have a [Drupal Commerce](http://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) site and I'd like to apply a discount to the price where it is calculated. I have a table in the profile user with SKU | discount pairs and I'd like some way (maybe [Rules](http://www.drupal.org/project/rules)?) to search the product on the table and apply the discount to the price.

Is there any way to do this in [Drupal Commerce](http://www.drupal.org/project/commerce)?

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Commerce Sale Price](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_saleprice) module with great success on my website. It is easy to configure. Just install and enable then you can set the discounts on the product pages.

Update: I think you could use [Commerce Coupon](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_coupon) to achieve your results. The coupons can be automatically applied based on a role. Sorry I did not understand your question fully before. Also, I have not used this module but the description appears to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But the problem with this approach is that the discounts on my website are per-user and not per-product. One user can have discounts in product one with x% off, two with y% off and three with z% off but another may have discounts in five with t% off seven with w% off and ten with r% off. The context seems to be pretty difficult to use Commerce Sale Price.

Comment: See updated answer...

Comment: Is it possible with Drupal Coupon to apply the discount for a certain product and user when Rules is computing the product price?

Comment: I would expect so but I couldn't be sure without trying. I know I have used a similar module for one site I developed that had Ubercart. Based on the description and my knowledge, I would be surprised if this module didn't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give solution for your the values which you saved in the user profile as I have never had that situation but I can give simple solution based on the requirement which I understood from your comment.

You can set several rules for discount based on no. of items in cart & user type.

[Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) work on 3 things - `Event`, `Condition` & `Action`.

So your **event** will be - `Completing the checkout process`.

**Condition** - `Total product quantity comparison` & `User has role(s)`.

**Action** - `Multiple the unit price by some amount` (Which you can set as per your discount model e.g. 0.95 for 5%, 0.92 for 8% etc).